# Is there any workflow tool or library in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipeline

I want to create 3 processes(a, b, c) and assemble them in a workflow.

```
ex: 
a---->b
b---->c
c---->end
```

output of a will send to input of b.

I tried ruffus but it designed for file transformation.

Is there workflow library in python?

Comment: I think you should look for "workflow" frameworks - not "pipeline".

Comment: @alfasin thx, I editted it.

Comment: editing your question won't help since in Stackoverflow we discourage asking members to recommend a tool/library/framework etc. But I'm sure that you can do a good job by googling it.

Comment: Read about [Pipes and Queues](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use taskflow
here's a
[taskflow doc](https://docs.openstack.org/taskflow/latest/)

it can add stage easily and don't worry about the parameters communication